# Проблема со связью в БД

Tags: sql, база-данных

Добрый день. Пытаюсь решить проблему со связями между сущностями "Клиент", "Личные данные клиента" и "Паспорт". Между Клиент и ЛДК должно быть 1 к 1 и между ЛДК и Паспорт аналогично. Каким образом это сделать? По идее идентификационный номер должен быть уникальным значением, но связать ЛДК и паспорт получается только через ID клиента... [image]

Comment: Так это и нормально. в паспорте пишите id клиента и все. Хотя собственный id ему так же не помешал бы. И кстати интересно, почему вы считаете паспорт-клиент отношения один к одному. А если паспорт поменяют, вы старый сотрете. А если паспортов несколько (гражданин нескольких стран, внутренний/загран, два заграна)

Comment: Схема, мягко говоря, не очень. Ограничить человека одним мобильным телефоном - это жестоко. А то, что у клиента может быть идентификационный номер, отличающийся от такового в его личных данных - совсем ерунда. В общем, составлять схему данных, не проанализировав до конца предметную область, не стОит.